# How to get list of parent, grandparent until root parent of an entity using JPA or JPQL with minimum select queries

Tags: jpa, jpql

The following is my domain class. I want to get list of parent, grand parent until root parent of an entity using JPQL or JPA relation.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity")
public class Entity {
 private Entity parent;
 public void setParent(Entity parent) {
  this.parent = parent;
 }

 @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name="parent_enty_id")
 public Entity getParent() {
  return this.parent;
 }
}
```